# Why using web services over remote connections?

Tags: odbc

Can we just use remote connections when we need to connect to remote database on remote server?
or we should use web services and what is the web service Architecture? is it differs when we use Lan or internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simple: web service are based on remote connections (TCP-connections) between server and client. However web services use standard formats to code and transport requests and answers. There are standard libraries for every platform, taking care of the communications.

The benefit of using web service over remote connections is that you do not have to bother with sockets, coding messages into streams and all the puzzle things. Instead you concentrate on your business logic.

In case of internet, you will need to access a proxy server to access internet. Almost every organisation has proxy server for HTTP and HTTPS, they can be used for web services directly. If you use your own remote connections, you may not able to configure the proxy server to let them through.